# AWS S3 Can't do anything with one file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I'm having issues trying to remove a file from my s3 bucket with the following name: Patrick bla bla 1 PV@05-06-2018-19:42:01.jpg

If I try to rename it through the s3 console, it just says that the operation failed. If I try to delete it, the operation will "succeed" but the file will still be there.

I've tried removing it through the aws cli, when listing the object I get this back

```
 {
        "LastModified": "2018-06-05T18:42:05.000Z",
        "ETag": "\"b67gcb5f8166cab8145157aa565602ab\"",
        "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
        "Key": "test/\bPatrick bla bla 1 PV@05-06-2018-19:42:01.jpg",
        "Owner": {
            "DisplayName": "dev",
            "ID": "bd65671179435c59d01dcdeag231786bbf6088cb1ca4881adf3f5e17ea7e0d68"
        },
        "Size": 1247277
    },
```

But if I try to delete or head it, the cli won't find it.

```
s3api head-object --bucket mybucket --key "test/\bPatrick bla bla 1 PV@05-06-2018-20:09:37.jpg"

An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found
```

Is there any way to remove, rename or just move this image from the folder?

Regards

Comment: Did you try escaping the backslash e.g. test/\\bPatrick...?

Comment: Just tried that, same result.

s3api head-object --bucket avondhupress --key "test/\\bPatrick bla bla 1 PV@05-06-2018-20:09:37.jpgg"

An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found

Comment: Might help to go back to the point it was created. Do you know what key it was created with? Maybe url-encoded backspace (\b) to %08.

Comment: That's how it was created, ever since it was inserted on the bucket there hasn't been any activity. How would I go about going back to before that point? Thanks!

Comment: In your s3api head-object test above (comment #2) your suffix was .jpgg. Was that simply a typo? Anyhow, by "go back to the point it was created", I mean that if the file was created by software then you presumably have that software and can try to understand what it does with non-standard characters.

Comment: Yeah that was indeed a typo. My bad. Is there any way to delete an object by etag? Seems like is not possible to target it via key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172608/discussion-between-jarmod-and-troyz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your object's key begins with a backspace (\b) character. I'm sure there is a way to manage this using the awscli but I haven't worked out what it is yet.

Here's a Python script that works for me:

```
import boto3 
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
Bucket ='avondhupress'
Key='test/\bPatrick bla bla 1 PV@05-06-2018-19:42:01.jpg'
s3.delete_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
```

Or the equivalent in node.js:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3({ region: 'us-east-1', signatureVersion: 'v4' });

const params = {
  Bucket: 'avondhupress',
  Key: '\bPatrick bla bla 1 PV@05-06-2018-19:42:01.jpg',
};

s3.deleteObject(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) console.error(err, err.stack);
});
```